# Mapping remote memory into the address space of a host using Inifiniband

Tags: infiniband, rdma, mellanox

I recently started to work with Infiniband cards, two Mellanox Technologies MT27700 Family [ConnectX-4] to be specific. Eventually, I want to extend an existing framework with interfaces based on the VPI Verbs API/RDMA CM API.

About the research I already did on RDMA programming: I started by reading [Mellanox' RDMA Aware Networks Programming User Manual](https://www.mellanox.com/related-docs/prod_software/RDMA_Aware_Programming_user_manual.pdf). Secondly, I read [a quite comprehensive blog](http://rdmamojo.com/) written on the capabilities of the VPI Verbs/RDMA Verbs. Finally, I read the three papers on RDMA programming, published by Tarick Bedeir: [[1]](http://www.hpcadvisorycouncil.com/pdf/building-an-rdma-capable-application-with-ib-verbs.pdf), [[2]](http://www.hpcadvisorycouncil.com/pdf/rdma-read-and-write-with-ib-verbs.pdf), [[3]](http://www.hpcadvisorycouncil.com/pdf/vendor_content/basic-flow-control-for-rdma-transfers.pdf).

To get an idea what is best for my needs, I created a testbench to measure, among others, latency, CPU usage, and throughput. I tested different operations (see table 1 below), different send flags (e.g. `IBV_SEND_INLINE`), and different ways of retrieving Work Completions (busy polling vs. waiting for an event in an completion channel). My testbench is partly inspired by the findings from [this performance study on RDMA programming](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6332248/).

```
OPCODE                      | IBV_QPT_UD | IBV_QPT_UC | IBV_QPT_RC
----------------------------+------------+------------+-----------
IBV_WR_SEND                 |     X      |     X      |     X
IBV_WR_SEND_WITH_IMM        |     X      |     X      |     X
IBV_WR_RDMA_WRITE           |            |     X      |     X
IBV_WR_RDMA_WRITE_WITH_IMM  |            |     X      |     X
IBV_WR_RDMA_READ            |            |            |     X
IBV_WR_ATOMIC_CMP_AND_SWP   |            |            |     X
IBV_WR_ATOMIC_FETCH_AND_ADD |            |            |     X
```

[[source of table 1]](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ibv_post_send)

Currently, I am still figuring out all possibilities.

One thing that I have noticed, is that I have to call `ibv_post_send` every time I want to write into the remote memory or read from the remote memory with `IBV_WR_RDMA_WRITE` or `IBV_WR_RDMA_READ`, respectively. So, my question is if it is possible to map the remote memory addresses into the virtual address space of a host.

Of course, all initialization of VPI components, registration of memory with `ibv_reg_mr`, and exchange of remote keys and addresses would still have to be done. Does Infiniband offer anything to make this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no native way to provide the functionality that you are looking for with RDMA. RDMA is designed as a networking protocol which relies on user applications to submit work requests of the forms defined above. However, although this isn't part of the original protocol, I believe it's not entirely impossible to implement a layer that will provide remote memory access through local memory space - but I'm not aware of any such system.

The closest thing that comes to mind is a memory disaggregation solution that basically lets you use remote memory when the local memory is fully utilized. Here's an example for such system: https://github.com/SymbioticLab/infiniswap